# jQuery parse xml Invalid XML: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Tags: jquery, rss, parsexml

I am trying to parse this xml with jquery: https://feed.podbean.com/talkloudradio.com/feed.xml

```
var url = https://feed.podbean.com/talkloudradio.com/feed.xml

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
    }).done(function( d ) {
            console.log($.parseXML( d.contents ))

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

    });
```

And I am getting error with parseXML:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If I try to search directly in done function with this, it doesnt find anything:

```
$(d).find("item").each(function(){
    console.log($(this))
})
```

What would be the issue, is it a valid rss?

Comment: `dataType: "xml"`

Comment: No, then it gets parsererror Error: Invalid XML, so it doesnt even parse it. If I do dataType:"json" it successfully parses it and returns  string in status contents.